# How can I say a job which completes 70-80%?

Tags: grammar, american-english

In English, if a job completed 100%, then I will say it is

> Completely done

If it is done about 50 %, we will say

> partially complete

How about case if it done about 60% to 70% or 70 to 80%?

Thank all

Comment: "Partially complete" is vague, and is open to interpretation, it  could encompass anything between 30%-60%. Likewise "nearly complete" could mean anything, it might need another day's work, or just the finishing touches. I would say ***The bulk of the work is/has been done*** http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/bulk Not perfect but it implies that most of the work, i.e. over 60%,  has been completed.

Comment: When it is 60% complete, you can use the English expression "60% complete". When it is 80% complete, a good fit is the expression "80% complete". Best of all: these are the *only* expressions that mean that. No other expression at all means the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could say "The job is almost complete."

Comment: Almost that means 90%, right?

Comment: more than half complete will cater to any percentage greater than 50.
almost complete in most cases would mean more than 80% although that can differ from person to person

Comment: @user8430 "almost" does not mean "90%". Language does not work that way. You must be trolling.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the followings:

> The job is (about) ***two thirds*** complete.

or

> The job is (about) ***three quarters*** complete.

Not only are they closer to the percentage you have in mind, but also they are idiomatic. You can check their usages in the linked [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two+thirds+complete%2Cthree+quarters+complete&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwo%20thirds%20complete%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthree%20quarters%20complete%3B%2Cc0).